# .NET2 Test if a string is a valid path

Tags: .net, .net-2.0

.NET methods like `Path.IsPathRooted()` are great, but throw if the input string isn't valid. Which is fine, but it would be nice to pre-check if an input string is a valid path before jumping into an exception-checking codeblock.

I can't see a `Path.IsValidPath()` or similar, is there something like this available?

Comment: Valid as in "path exists" or in "path conforms to formal criteria"?

Comment: Valid as it will it throw an exception with the `Path` methods :)

Comment: @Ani I don't think this is quite the same question - surely some valid URIs would cause an Exception in `Path.IsRooted()` for example?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation,

> `ArgumentException` [is thrown when] path contains one or more of the invalid characters defined in GetInvalidPathChars.

This means that you can pre-validate your path strings as follows:

```
if (path.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) != -1) {
    // This means that Path.IsPathRooted will throw an exception
    ....
}
```

This is the only condition under which `IsPathRooted` throws an exception.

Take a look at [Mono source of `Path.cs`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs), line 496, for details on how this is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `File.Exists` or `Directory.Exists`.

If you want to check if a path contains illegal chars (on NET 2.0) you can use [`Path.GetInvalidPathChars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
char[] invalidChars = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
bool valid = path.IndexOfAny(invalidChars) != -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool ValidPathString(string path)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) return false;
    char[] invalidPathChars = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
    foreach (char c in invalidPathChars)
    {
        if(path.Contains(c)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```